# javascript logging on form submit

Tags: javascript, magento, logging, form-submit, worldpay

In several of websites I maintain/develop we use worldpay as the payment gateway. We have people experiencing strange problems with it. So I tried logging some stuff and the logging I implemented does not quite work.

The problem that users experience is that they are supposed to be redirected to worldpay website, so magento plugin generates a simple form with hidden fields. Then on page load event it submits the form. Form action url is set to worldpay url. So it's basicaly a post request with order info being sent to worldpay.

Now for some people, and this happens on a daily basis the worldpay gateway never loads. They are stuck on a page with hidden form that says please standby while we redirect you. We had people wait for several minutes before actually being redirected.

I decided to start logging various stuff from that form whenever the user spends more than 3 seconds on it. So I turned to javascript this is what I have done:

```
<body onload="javascript:document.worldpay_checkout.submit()">
```

Then I have these lines

```
function timerFunction(){
    var dataObj = {};
    for (var i = document.worldpay_checkout.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        dataObj[document.worldpay_checkout.elements[i].name] = document.worldpay_checkout.elements[i].value;
    }
    dataObj["BrowserCodeName="] = navigator.appCodeName;
    dataObj["BrowserName="] = navigator.appName;
    dataObj["BrowserVersion="] = navigator.appVersion;
    dataObj["CookiesEnabled="] = navigator.cookieEnabled;
    dataObj["Platform="] = navigator.platform;
    dataObj["UserAgentHeader="] = navigator.userAgent;
    $.post("/worldpaylog/worldpaylog.php", dataObj, function(data) {
        document.worldpay_checkout.submit();
        intervalId = self.setInterval('timerFunction()',5000);
    });
    self.clearInterval(intervalId); 
}
var intervalId = self.setInterval('timerFunction()',3000);
```

What I try to do is get the form elements and some browser info and log that on the server by making an ajax post request if more than 3 seconds have passed. Then I re-submit the form. It looks pretty straight forward to me yet there are still a lot of ppl. who do not get to worldpay and are not logged by the script. Could it be that on some browsers javascript is not reliable after submitting a form? before the browser starts expecting a new page load or whatever.

Also, there is a minified jquery framework with just the components needed for ajax function to work on that page. I found it on github out of desperation thinking what I wrote before did not work on all browsers. But it's all the same.

Does anyone have any hints on what I should do here? Maybe an idea on different approach to logging this data or something?

Comment: Why don't you trigger logging on actual submit element? http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Just a point : you shall not use setInterval with a function as parameter, because it uses eval as stated here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setInterval

Use instead setInterval(timerFunction, 5000);

Comment: I'll change the call to timer function. I do not log on submit because I wanted to log only people who spent more than 3 seconds on the page. As it looked to me like they are the ones who might have a problem.

Also, the initial idea was to resubmit the form after 3 seconds. To simulate a browser refresh. Then I wanted to log those and just those incidents.

Comment: Why aren't you using setTimeout? You wouldn't need to store the interval id just to clear it when the function is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the error is that there is a JavaScript bug that kills the scripts, so you get no redirecting and no logging. Watch out for jQuery ajax request errors getting swallowed up without issue and make sure that you check your code works in as many browsers as possible.

You could temporarily try logging errors thrown on the page by registering an event handler with window.onerror. Not all browsers support this event or will trigger on all errors, but it provides a starting point for probing for JavaScript errors on the client if you are unable to identify these yourself with your own testing.